# Show that $plim A_n = plim B_n$ implies $plim V(A_n) = plim V(B_n)$

Tags: measure-theory, asymptotics, expected-value, variance

Let $A_n$ and $B_n$ be two sequences of random variables in $\mathbb{R}^K$ for $K\geq 1$. I  would like to show that $plim V(A_n) = plim V(B_n)$. I have the following information

- $plim A_n = plim B_n$.
- $A_n - B_n$ is uniformly square integrable; that is, for each component of $A_n - B_n$, the sequence made of the square is uniformly integrable.

I succeeded to prove the statement for $K = 1$ but I am unable to generalize it.
As $A_n-B_n$ is uniformly square integrable, the improved dominance convergence theorem ([Lebesgue–Vitali theorem](https://www.bibmath.net/dico/index.php?action=affiche&quoi=./v/vitalitheoreme.html#:%7E:text=Le%20th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me%20de%20Vitali%20(parfois,vers%20f%20dans%20L1%20.&text=(fn)%20converge%20en%20mesure,fn)%20est%20uniform%C3%A9ment%20int%C3%A9grable.)) implies that $plim V(A_n-B_n) = V(plim A_n-plim B_n) = 0$.

If $A_n$ and $B_n$ are scalars, then $V(A_n-B_n) = V(A_n) + V(B_n) - 2COV(A_n, B_n) \geq V(A_n) + V(B_n) - 2V(A_n)^{1/2}V(B_n)^{1/2}$, because  $COV(A_n, B_n)\leq V(A_n)^{1/2}V(B_n)^{1/2}$. Thus, $V(A_n-B_n) \geq \left(V(A_n)^{1/2} - V(B_n)^{1/2}\right)^2 \geq 0$. Therefore $plim V(A_n) = plim V(B_n)$ since $plim V(A_n-B_n) = 0$.

I thought that it would be easy to generalize it to vector random variables. But I cannot do it. The condition $COV(A_n, B_n)\leq V(A_n)^{1/2}V(B_n)^{1/2}$ originates from Cauchy Schwarz inequality and the multivariate version seems completely different to me.

Comment: The multivariate version of cauchy-schwarz that I know is \begin{equation}
\mathrm{Var}(B_n) \ge \mathrm{Cov}(B_n,A_n) \mathrm{Var}(A_n)^{-1} \mathrm{Cov}(A_n,B_n)
\end{equation}

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to use it here.